# babel/core and babel/polyfill is not working for nodejs

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill, babel-core

```
"devDependencies": {

"@babel/cli": "^7.17.6",

"@babel/core": "^7.17.8",

"@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",

"@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11"
}
}
```

This is my development dependencies and i keep getting the issue on the terminal;

```
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.12.1:  This package has been deprecated in favor of separate inclusion of a polyfill and regenerator-runtime (when needed). See the @babel/polyfill docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) for more information.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@\<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

Anybody know why this is happening?

I was just going to use babel in my project and some of them didn't work somehow.

Comment: Did you read the linked docs?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the same things but it is still not working. Which packages should i use?